# aggregate multiple columns in a data frame at once calculating different statistics on different columns - R

Tags: r, aggregate

I am trying to perform what should be a simple exercise of aggregating columns in a dataframe by the first column.   Each column is aggregated with a summary statistic, but they are not the same.   For example several columns I need the mean, several I need standard deviation, several I need the max value, etc.    I am using documentation with the aggregate function within R and for some reason can't get it.

Can you help?

Attached is a simple example data set.   For illustration purposes I need to aggregate by the "name" column.   Var1 I need the mean, Var2 I need the standard deviation, Var3 I need the max value, Var4 I would like the sum

```
name    v1  v2  v3  v4  v5
a     78    74  43  76  61
b     50    84  76  73  35
c     4    55   4   86  32
d     23    29  81  73  55
e     36    68  27  70  96

# A tibble: 11 x 5
   name     v1    v2    v3    v4
   <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
 1 a        78   NaN    43    76
 2 b        50   NaN    76    73
 3 c         4   NaN     4    86
 4 d        23   NaN    81    73
 5 e        36   NaN    27    70
 6 f        13   NaN    34    77
 7 g         2   NaN    57    79
 8 h        72   NaN    29     3
 9 i        17   NaN    56    14
10 j        87   NaN    36    13
11 k         9   NaN    74    41
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `dplyr` for flexibility

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(name) %>% 
     summarise(v1 = mean(v1, na.rm = TRUE),
    v2 = sd(v2, na.rm = TRUE), v3 = max(v3, na.rm = TRUE),
            v4 = sum(v4, na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

If there are multiple columns to be blocked for different functions, use `across`

```
df1 %>%
    group_by(name) %>%
    summarise(across(c(v1, v2), mean, na.rm = TRUE),
               v3 = sd(v3, na.rm = TRUE),
               across(c(v4, v5), sum, na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

Or use `collap` from `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
collap(df1, ~ name, custom = list(fmean = c("v1", "v2"),
      fsd = "v3", fsum = c("v4", "v5")))
```

Comment: thank you for this!   I copied my results from this above.   One issue I got was the summary for the sd(v2) was NaN.   Can you help me with this?

Comment: @DataScienceDave most of the function you specified in the post have `na.rm = FALSE` by default, change it to TRUE (as in the update).  For `collapse`, the functions have `na.rm = TRUE` by default

Comment: @DataScienceDave `sd` if the group have only a single observation, it returns NA i.e. `sd(5, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] NA`

Comment: thank you @akrun however the data I am testing this with has many observations, no NA values, and using str() they are all integers.    I'm still getting the error after using your update.   Any idea what I'm doing wrong?    Also, how do I update the df1 with the summary statistics.   I am wanting to use this for a cluster exercise

Comment: @DataScienceDave your input shows only 5 rows and each name a single observation.  If you can update your post with `dput(head(yourdata, 30))`, I can test it

Comment: I.e. update your post with a small reproducible example so that it can be tested. (please make sure the 'name' column have at least 2 or more observations per unique value)

Comment: structure(list(name = structure(1:11, .Label = c("a", "b", "c", 
"d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"), class = "factor"), v1 = c(78L, 
50L, 4L, 23L, 36L, 13L, 2L, 72L, 17L, 87L, 9L), v2 = c(74L, 84L, 
55L, 29L, 68L, 69L, 42L, 29L, 54L, 91L, 27L), v3 = c(43L, 76L, 
4L, 81L, 27L, 34L, 57L, 29L, 56L, 36L, 74L), v4 = c(76L, 73L, 
86L, 73L, 70L, 77L, 79L, 3L, 14L, 13L, 41L), v5 = c(61L, 35L, 
32L, 55L, 96L, 93L, 76L, 34L, 9L, 38L, 100L)), row.names = c(NA, 
11L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: sorry @akrun I should have provided the dput at the start!

Comment: @DataScienceDave that data you showed have `df1$name
 [1] a b c d e f g h i j k` only one observation per name

Comment: on no I can't believe I did that!  You are exactly right, my sample data didn't have the right data.   Thank you very much for the help.   I expanded the data and it works wonderfully